# Installing lablgtk on Linux

Tags: linux, software-installation, configure

Hi I am running Linux Mint 18.2 and am trying to install lablgtk for Ocaml (4.05.0). In the README, findlib 1.2.1 is necessary so I tried installing that.

When I try to ./configure for findlib I get two messages:

> labltk: not present
>
> camlp4: not present

So I downloaded camlp4 and then tried downloading labltk. When I tried ./configure for labltk I got the message:

> Configuring LablTk...
> runtest: gcc -O2 -fno-strict-aliasing -fwrapv
>
> -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_REENTRANT -o tst not found tclversion.c  -lm  -ldl
>
> gcc: error: not: No such file or directory
>
> gcc: error: found: No such file or directory
>
> runtest: gcc -O2 -fno-strict-aliasing -fwrapv
>
> -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_REENTRANT -o tst -I/usr/local/include not found tclversion.c  -lm  -ldl
>
> gcc: error: not: No such file or directory
>
> gcc: error: found: No such file or directory
>
> runtest: gcc -O2 -fno-strict-aliasing -fwrapv -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_REENTRANT -o tst -I/opt/local/include not found tclversion.c  -lm  -ldl
>
> gcc: error: not: No such file or directory gcc: error: found: No such file or directory
>
> runtest: gcc -O2 -fno-strict-aliasing -fwrapv -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_REENTRANT -o tst -I/sw/include not found tclversion.c  -lm  -ldl
>
> gcc: error: not: No such file or directory
>
> gcc: error: found: No such file or directory
>
> runtest: gcc -O2
> -fno-strict-aliasing -fwrapv -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_REENTRANT -o tst -I/usr/pkg/include not found tclversion.c  -lm  -ldl gcc: error:
> not: No such file or directory gcc: error: found: No such file or
> directory runtest: gcc -O2 -fno-strict-aliasing -fwrapv
> -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_REENTRANT -o tst -I/usr/include not found tclversion.c  -lm  -ldl gcc: error: not: No such file or directory
> gcc: error: found: No such file or directory runtest: gcc -O2
> -fno-strict-aliasing -fwrapv -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_REENTRANT -o tst -I/usr/local/include/tcl8.6 -I/usr/local/include/tk8.6 not found
> tclversion.c  -lm  -ldl gcc: error: not: No such file or directory
> gcc: error: found: No such file or directory runtest: gcc -O2
> -fno-strict-aliasing -fwrapv -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_REENTRANT -o tst -I/usr/include/tcl8.6 -I/usr/include/tk8.6 not found tclversion.c
> -lm  -ldl gcc: error: not: No such file or directory gcc: error: found: No such file or directory runtest: gcc -O2 -fno-strict-aliasing
> -fwrapv -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_REENTRANT -o tst -I/usr/local/include/tcl8.5 -I/usr/local/include/tk8.5 not found tclversion.c  -lm  -ldl gcc: error: not: No such file or directory
> gcc: error: found: No such file or directory runtest: gcc -O2
> -fno-strict-aliasing -fwrapv -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_REENTRANT -o tst -I/usr/include/tcl8.5 -I/usr/include/tk8.5 not found tclversion.c
> -lm  -ldl gcc: error: not: No such file or directory gcc: error: found: No such file or directory runtest: gcc -O2 -fno-strict-aliasing
> -fwrapv -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_REENTRANT -o tst -I/usr/local/include/tcl8.4 -I/usr/local/include/tk8.4 not found tclversion.c  -lm  -ldl gcc: error: not: No such file or directory
> gcc: error: found: No such file or directory runtest: gcc -O2
> -fno-strict-aliasing -fwrapv -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_REENTRANT -o tst -I/usr/include/tcl8.4 -I/usr/include/tk8.4 not found tclversion.c
> -lm  -ldl gcc: error: not: No such file or directory gcc: error: found: No such file or directory runtest: gcc -O2 -fno-strict-aliasing
> -fwrapv -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_REENTRANT -o tst -I/usr/local/include/tcl8.3 -I/usr/local/include/tk8.3 not found tclversion.c  -lm  -ldl gcc: error: not: No such file or directory
> gcc: error: found: No such file or directory runtest: gcc -O2
> -fno-strict-aliasing -fwrapv -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_REENTRANT -o tst -I/usr/include/tcl8.3 -I/usr/include/tk8.3 not found tclversion.c
> -lm  -ldl gcc: error: not: No such file or directory gcc: error: found: No such file or directory runtest: gcc -O2 -fno-strict-aliasing
> -fwrapv -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_REENTRANT -o tst -I/usr/local/include/tcl8.2 -I/usr/local/include/tk8.2 not found tclversion.c  -lm  -ldl gcc: error: not: No such file or directory
> gcc: error: found: No such file or directory
> runtest: gcc -O2
> -fno-strict-aliasing -fwrapv -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_REENTRANT -o tst -I/usr/include/tcl8.2 -I/usr/include/tk8.2 not found tclversion.c
> -lm  -ldl
>
> gcc: error: not: No such file or directory
>
> gcc: error: found: No such file or directory
>
> tcl.h and/or tk.h not found.
>
> ** Configuration summary **
>
> The "labltk" library: not supported

I've checked my package manager and I have tcl, tk, tcl-dev, and tk-dev 8.6.0+9 installed.

I really don't know what to try next but I need the Gtk interface for Ocaml. Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to figure out what is generating the "not found" which is interpolating into the command lines configure is generating - it's going to be some further missing dependency.

Have you tried using the distro-packaged versions of all this? They should have all the problems solved.  Mint has packages that would seem to be applicable, for example (not sure *exactly* what you are looking for):

```
p   liblablgtk2-ocaml               - runtime libraries for OCaml bindings for G
p   liblabltk-ocaml                 - OCaml bindings to Tcl/Tk (runtime librarie
```

and so on.